# How does Potion Toxicity work in The Witcher 2?

Tags: the-witcher-2

I know that every potion in The Witcher 2 has a "toxicity", but both the manual and the game provide less than adequate explanations of what toxicity *is*, and how it works.

For instance, much of the latter half of the Alchemist tree deals with effects 'while intoxicated'. What does it mean to become 'intoxicated', and what are its effects?

What do the green and red bars on the potion toxicity meter mean? In gameplay, I haven't noticed any apparent effect from using past the green, and I haven't dared to toxic-ify myself into the red.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Being intoxicated is not like in The Witcher, where you used to start shaking and lose control of Geralt.

Here, intoxication level only limits the amount of potions you can pour down.

Some talents allow you, so to speak, to "spread this poison" to your enemies. 
They are the type "+xx to yyy .. while intoxicated"

Excerpt from an interview with [Tomasz Gop](http://witchervault.ign.com/View.php?view=Editorials.Detail&id=7):

> WV: How many potions can Geralt drink in one sitting? Assuming zero alchemy skills and minimal toxicity of each of the potions? How does the overdose look in Witcher 2?
>
> Tomasz Gop: Well, you have to understand that right now, drinking potions is done during meditation only. You have a **projected level of toxicity shown in a bar** when adding potions to the batch you're going to drink before leaving meditation. **This level cannot be exceeded**.
>
> WV: Hang on, what about the overdose then? We've heard about a possibility to overdose potions -- unlike in Witcher 1, it was supposed to be something akin to actual poisoning, whereby Geralt starts shaking uncontrollably and you lose control of your character for a while...
>
> Tomasz Gop: Unfortunately, **there's no overdose this time**. It's not that we had to cut out this part, we just didn't have time to add that feature.

Comment: So drink as much as I want, whenever I want, with whomever I want, no consequences?

Comment: You can't drink as much as you want. As soon as you reach a high level of toxicity you need to let time pass for it to swallow another one.

`with whomever I want`: are we still talking about potions?

Comment: @Bora - at what point are you considered intoxicated for Alchemist abilities?

Comment: @Raven The manual does not say anything, and I am not that far in the ability progression.. My guess is, there is not a lower bound to being intoxicated. As soon as level level > 0 you are considered intoxicated. However, it is most certain, that the effects of those alchemist abilities increase in direct proportion to toxicity level = The more the better.

Comment: @Bora - there is nothing in the skills that lends any support to a notion that "the more intoxicated the better".

Comment: @Raven In the interview, there is a passage that mentions about that. Search for `The more poisoned Geralt is, the greater the bonuses you can get to damage dealt or health.`

Comment: @Bora - okay, but *in the game* there is nothing to indicate the abilities of the alchemist tree change based on *how* badly you are intoxicated.

Comment: @Raven Well, I guess it is because the developers didn't have time to elaborate on this aspect of the game, as Tomasz admits during the interview. I know, I have not much of an evidence to back my answer up, but that's what there is :)

Answer (score 7):

As i found contradicting statements about what level of toxicity is needed to gain the effect of many talents in the alchemy tree i tested it out.
I did 71 damage against an enemy creature.
Then I learned the taster and the Metathesis talents (both 2/2) with should raise my damage about 40% while intoxicated. Drank a Swallow potion which in itself did not change my damage dealt. After that against the same enemy i hit for 100 damage, which is indeed about 40% more than 71. So:

with only one potion and toxicity level of 25 I got the benefits of the "while poisoned" talents!