# What does "when poisoned" mean in talent descriptions and how can I reliably become poisoned?

Tags: the-witcher-2

The second half of the alchemist tree consist entirely of talents that depend on Geralt being poisoned. What exactly does it mean in the context and is there any way to induce poisoning at will?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Poisoned is a misleading term here - what really triggers this is **toxicity,** which is increased the more potions you drink at one time.  The toxicity of each potion varies, but you can see it when you look at a potion's recipe or when you add it to your active potions during meditation.  The bar that fills as you add potions is your toxicity meter.

Drinking a combination of potions that pushes your toxicity meter near the maximum will put you into a state where these bonuses are applied.

We also covered potion toxicity in this question:

[How does Potion Toxicity work in The Witcher 2?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/23107/how-does-potion-toxicity-work-in-the-witcher-2)

Comment: I thought that would be the case. Any idea exactly how much toxicity counts as being "poisoned"? Can I be poisoned but not have the annoying heartbeat sound? Does the Taster perk, which lets you drink more potions, change how many potions you need to drink to become poisoned?

Comment: I'm not alchemy spec'ed, so I don't have a lot of experience getting into this state.  I've seen some conflicting reports on how much toxicity is required - some people say you've got to get it to the orange, and others say just one potion is enough.  I don't believe Taster effects maximum toxicity though.